# difference between visual studio 2008 and visual studio 2010

Tags: visual-studio-2010, visual-studio-2008

I want to know what is the main difference between vs2008 and vs2010..
means I want to know what is the new functionality added in vs2010.

Comment: these links will definitely http://codereflex.net/searching-and-navigation-in-visualstudio-2010/ http://codereflex.net/difference-between-vs2010-and-vs2008-multiple-monitor-support/

Answer (score 3):

Well, there's always [Microsoft's page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb386063.aspx) about the new features of VS 2010.  But you can get a more distilled [user perspective](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020111715/https://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/041410-1.aspx) describing new features that specific developers really like.  There are a number of [blog posts](http://www.google.com/search?q=visual+studio+2010+features) about it as well.

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to code a lot with threads, definitely go with 2010. It has great advancements on the profiler and debugger. The profiler especially it's awesome.