# Opening projects and solutions in different versions of Visual Studio

Tags: .net, vb.net, visual-studio

Why can't you open a project or solution that was developed using one version of visual studio in another version of visual studio?

I understand that solutions contain projects and projects contain files e.g. aspx, vb etc.  I also understand that one version of visual studio could default to targeting one version of .NET and the another could target a different version of .NET.  Therefore I understand that it may be necessary to change code in the application if it now targets a different version of .NET as functions could be depreciated etc in a new version.

I expected to find an answer to this online, but I have not.  For example, I have looked at the following question: [difference between visual studio 2008 and visual studio 2010](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5417592/difference-between-visual-studio-2008-and-visual-studio-2010).

Comment: probably like every program they have backward comparability. you can open VS2008 project in VS2010, however in VS2010 there are new features that were added. so now the project files looks different.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Visual Studio 2012, they addressed this issue (I agree, it can be a pain).  In 2012, it will not modify the project file, so you can continue to open the project in 2010 after you've opened it in 2012.  This allows teams with mixed Visual Studio versions (2010 & 2012) to continue working on the same projects.

If you don't have VS 2012, and are still using 2010, then once you upgrade the project to the new version (say, from 2008 to 2010), you can no longer open the project in the older version, unfortunately.

I'm not sure about your development environment, but if you don't already have it, there are free express versions of VS 2012 available: http://www.microsoft.com/visualstudio/eng/products/visual-studio-express-products.

Comment: Thanks.  +1 for the reference to VS2012.  Does it prompt you when the solution is opened in VS2012? (if say the project was created in VS2008)?

Comment: Unfortunately, I don't think it works for VS2008, only VS2010 SP1, from what I've seen.  And it may still prompt you to upgrade to the 2012 format, but it is backward compatible with 2010 SP1.  Here is a MSFT article on compatibility in 2012: http://msdn.microsoft.com/sv-SE/library/hh266747(v=vs.110)

Answer (score 1):

If you open an older project in vs 2010, it should prompt you to use a conversion wizard and you can convert to a vs 2010 project.  If you are trying to open a newer project in an older version of vs, that is not going to be supported.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to retrospectively open projects or solutions with different versions of VS by editing the version of the .sln or csproj file in notepad. There are some tools to download that do this automatically. But the problem is that the project will normally be built with a target framework not supported by the earlier version. I've done it in the past when I only had VS2005 and a contractor was using VS2010 but targetted at Framework V2.0. Not worth it in my opinion, I bought VS2010.

Comment: Thanks.  Do you know if it is just the version that has to be edited?

Comment: It's been a long while since i did it but I think its just <ProductVersion> & <TargetFrameworkVersion>